# how to import vectors from fireworks to illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-fireworks

I created some vector graphics for my company's website in fireworks because I like the pixel perfect control I get but now everybody likes the artwork so much that they want to use it all over the place, even for some large posters.

I want to create an illustrator version but when I paste the vectors from fireworks to illustrator they get rasterized. Anyone know if there's a way to import from fireworks to illustrator and keep the artwork as vectors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you, Crates, saving as "FXG and Images" in Adobe Fireworks CS5 worked like a charm in AI CS5. Finally, a solution! Why do they have to make things SOOOOOO difficult between the two. I know it was acquired from Macromedia.. but now it has been Adobe for several releases... get with the program.

Answer (score 11):

File -> Export -> Choose "FXG and Images" in the drop-down for file type.

This produces a much higher quality vector map than the AI8 "Save As" format does.

Comment: How do you then import this into Illustrator? If I open the file, it simply displays the markup

Answer (score 3):

Save as > Illustrator 8 AI format selected from drop-down for file format.

Comment: This does work, but I did get much better results with @Crates answer.

Answer (score -3):

Save as Fireworks PNG (which is an Adobe extension of bitmap PNG that supports vectors etc)
Goto above illustrator and open same file in that.
Adobe products share many file formats in common.

Comment: PNG is a **raster** format. The question is specifically asking about transferring vector data.

Comment: Note.. vector data in Fireworks PNG files is **only** visible to Fireworks. No other application will ever see any vector data within a PNG file.

Comment: @Scott almost. Flash and Fireworks have a long history together: you can import/paste from a Fireworks png and the vectors will be preserved